Help designing a 24 to 5 volt converter
I am making a robot arm. I have a 24 volt 17 amp power supply which powers the motors, but I also need 5 volts for the microcontroller and about 30 sensors. So I made this 24 to 5 volt converter circuit in Microsoft OneNote. I only have a basic understanding of circuits, so I don't know if this will work. Is the circuit good? Will it output a stable 5 volts?

This link creates a copy of the parts I plan on using from DigiKey:
https://www.digikey.ca/short/wtbmpc72

Your motor controller must limit current below supply limit , otherwise it will fail. Motors demand >10x rated current on full power start. My guess from your experience level is this is not a good plan.  Also the 5V regulator will not work well with your design info so far. You would be better off in every way buying this regulator board and you may need a LiFeO4 battery too.

I looked at your history to see a 6A 1/3 ohm 2V 12 watt stepper motor. Why the heck do you need a 24 V supply for that???  Bad design.  24V  is for fast acceleration low torque. because it will current  limit from 24V down to  2V in 1/200th of a turn.  Why don't you start over and state the physics of your robot arm. Starting with momentum, torque, rasdial velocy acceleration inertia . Do you know the motor will melt your human hand as it's max steady torque. Can you start over with good specs

D.A.S, I'm not using that motor. Plus it was more like 30 volts

30V , microstepping and direct drive is the reason why your design failed for torque. Wouldn't you rather have a perfect solution, rather than mundane bandaids? But need to define your requirements.  and be specific about what parts you MUST use or might consider if something is much better.  The 5V spec is trivial.  The real problem is your servo.

The datasheet shows 2 x 22uF capacitors across the output for a total of 44uF. This means they should be in parallel but you have them in series which gives you 11uF. Other than that I don’t see any other obvious problems.
If it works and is stable depends largely on how it is constructed. There is a layout guide in the datasheet, following that should get you a properly working circuit.

If you have no experience with DC/DC converters, designing one that works well will take a lot of time. Layout is extremely important and it is easy to make fatal mistakes. Thus, in your situations, there are three reasons to want to design a DC/DC converter yourself:

You want to learn about designing DC/DC converters. This justifies the time investment.

You need it as cheap as possible because you'll make a large quantity of boards. The time investment will be amortized.

You want something special that is not offered by an off the shelf solution, for example an unusual input voltage, or extra low standby power.


Note that "I need 5V for a project" is not part of this list. If that is the reason, then the solution to your actual problem (ie, you need some 5V) is to spend 3-5€ on an off the shelf solution. This will save you many hours and potential problems, and in the end, if you value your time and have other stuff to do on your project than debugging a DC/DC, it is much cheaper.
It's not magic or rocket science, but it takes time, and if the layout is screwed, then you have to redo the board, and that's extremely annoying.
For DIY projects, I could absolutely spend a few hours designing a DC/DC converter.  Instead I either copypaste a known-working, debugged design, or just drop a 3€ RECOM unit and I'm done with it, every single time. Life is too short to spend hours to save 50 cents ;)
Here is the mouser search page for 24V in, 5V out DC/DC converters.
I like this one, it's small, efficient, practical, just add a bunch of extra caps and you're done.
I can't recommend any though, because you haven't said anything about how much current you need.
So, the first thing to do is to decide:

How much current you need for your "microcontroller and about 30 sensors", you can measure it or estimate it

If you need it isolated or not isolated. Non-isolated is cheaper and more efficient, but isolated will save your day if you have high current ground loops.


Then look into the list, sort by price, and done.
And do not buy counterfeit LM2596 from aliexpress.

What’s wrong with counterfeit electronic modules from aliexpress?

Inductor saturates all the time, caps are high ESR and get super hot, huge ripple, bad regulation, it won't last long

Just adding three small points:
One, to further emphasize: heed comments about layout.  In particular, the loop between regulator and 2.2µF must be very small: a few mm at most.  Make connections relative to that ground point, and use ground pour/plane where possible.  (I won't go into further detail here, as such questions have been asked many many times and are easy to find.)
Two, consider this series of posts discussing situations with the input capacitor: 
Correct Placement of Series Ferrite Beads to Avoid DC Disconnect During Power Cycling 
To summarize: you may want an electrolytic in parallel with the 2.2µF.
Three, you probably want a local fuse, so that the main supply's full 17A+ output is not available through the small wires feeding this circuit, or its thin traces and pins (or at least, not for very long).  Any type will do, with 28V or higher and 1A ratings being typical.  If choosing a PTC type, make sure its resistance Rmin is high enough such that (24V) / Rmin < Imax.

For the electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the 2.2µF capacitor, would a 100 µF 50 V aluminum electrolytic capacitor be a good choice?

Like this: https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/nichicon/UUN1H101MNJ1MS/4995171

Probably, but doesn't need to be bipolar which adds cost and size. Something like Nichicon UUD1H101MNL1GS would likely do well.
